# Which Inversion of control (IoC) containers support .NET 1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Which Inversion of control (IoC) containers support .NET 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

One is the Castle Project's [Castle Microkernel/Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html).

Comment: Note that 1.1 support was dropped several months (12+) ago, so you can only get old builds for 1.1